# Laravel 5.6 Model relation and Array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Contorller@edit**

```
public function edit(Choice $choice){
    $choice = Choice::find($choice->id);
    return view('choices.edit',compact('choice'));
}
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::model($choice, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['choices.update', $choice->id]]) !!}
<input class="form-control" step="1" min="0" value="{{ $choice->question_number }}" max="" type="number" name="number"></input><br/>
{!! Form::submit('Шинэчлэх', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Model of Choice**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'time',
    'topic_id',
    'question_number'
];

public function topic(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
}
```

> Im trying to set MAX in view's input by that one(bottom of this one).

**And here is it**

```
$duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->with('topic', 'topic.choices')->groupBy('topic_id')->get()->toArray();

array:34 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
  "total" => 30                     <<<<<<<< TRYING TO SET BY MAX 
  "topic_id" => 1
  "topic" => array:6 [▶]
]
```

Comment: Why are you doing `Choice::find($choice->id)` ?

Comment: Editing in view by choice ID. `['choices.update', $choice->id]`

Comment: Yes but you're already using model binding to find the model. You're just finding the same thing twice.

Comment: oops thank you nevermind. Can you help me in this struggle.